# How to cancel WM_CLOSE on winEventFilter?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt4, signals

I created simple [handler inside my QApplication](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#winEventFilter):

```
bool QtMyApplication::winEventFilter ( MSG * msg, long * result ){
    switch(msg->message) {
        case WM_CLOSE:{
            qDebug() << "Haha Not killing appp =)";
            *result = 0;
            return true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And I started my application, opened Task Manager, called `End Task` on my qt Application and in a fiew seconds got message:

[image]

I also got same results for implementing [QWidget WinEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#winEvent) on my [`QMainWindow`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html):

```
bool QMyMainWindow::winEvent(MSG *message, long *result)
{
    switch(message->message) {
        case WM_CLOSE:{
            qDebug() << "Haha Not killing appp =)";
            *result = 0;
            return true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return QMainWindow::winEvent(message, result);
}
```

Note application and Task Manager were started from `Administrator` on `Windows Server 8 r2`

So I wonder how to handle `WM_CLOSE` sent by Task Manager on `QApplication` or `QMainWindow` so that `End Programm` message would not be shown?

Comment: @ratchetfreak: All I want is to show to the user my window (allow to save files before quit etc)!

Answer (score 1):

A better (and less platform-specific) way to do this, rather than looking for window system close events, is to re-implement the Qt closeEvent function in your main window. Assuming your application has the [quitOnLastWindowClosed](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qguiapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop) flag set, it quits once the window closes.

In your main window code, implement [closeEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#closeEvent)

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    if(want_to_check)
    {
        int result = QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Are you sure"),
                    tr("Are you sure you want to exit?"),
                    QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
            if(result==QMessageBox::Yes)
            {
                    // You can save files, etcetera, here
                    event->accept(); // The event is accepted, the window will close, and the application will exit
            }
            else
            {       // Your window will not close, and application will stay open
                    event->ignore(); // The window will stay open
            }
         }
    }
```

Comment: I also tried to use closeEvent - sadly task manager shows `End Task` message in about 3 seconds anyway=(

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it seems the real question is how to ask the user about saving files before being closed by the Task Manager.  It's an odd question because closing an application from the Task Manager is typically a last resort.

It's perfectly reasonable to ask the user about saving files when they try to close the application in a common way, like choosing Exit from the menu or clicking the close button on the main window.  So go ahead and handle WM_CLOSE to do that.

But keep in mind that there are lots of other ways a process can be terminated.  For example, the user might log out or shut down the computer or the power may go out or your program may crash because of a bug or, just possibly, the user might try to kill the process from Task Manager (maybe because it hung).

In these cases, you don't really have an option to present an interactive question.

Option 1:  Save the file without asking.  You could save it with a distinct file name so that the original is still available if the user intentionally skipped the save.  The next time the application starts, it could check to see if any of these "emergency saves" are lying around and then ask the user which copy he/she wants to use.

Option 2:  Eliminate the concept of saving.  Keep the file up-to-date as the user edits the in-memory copy.  This can be tricky to make everything transactional so that the file is never left in a bad state, but it's appropriate for certain types of applications.

Option 3:  Auto-save at intervals (which is a simplified way of implementing Option 2).  That way, if the process dies, the user loses only the changes since the last auto-save.